# Radio button values and submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button, submit-button

I am writing a program that takes 3 questions and decides if any of them have the value of 0. Then when you hit submit it sends you to the next page which will write something based on if the value was 0 or 1. If it was 0 for any of them it should say false and if it is 1 for all then it should write pass.

When I click a radio button it will write false or pass correctly but this is only supposed to happen if the submit button is pressed. When I hit the submit button after selecting a radio button it changes the written words to pass no matter what is selected. 
When I have the onclick function to write pass/false on a different page it doesn't write anything. Can I not do this with just JavaScript?
I need to be able to launch a new page that will either have more questions on it or that will then have results written to it. I was trying to use the least amount of pages possible.

I have the HTML and JavaScript files on their own pages.

This is the HTML page

```
<form id="myForm">
    <fieldset class="article">
        <h3>
            <legend>Eligibility Test</legend>
        </h3>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="article">      
        <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="field1" value="0" onclick="getscores1(this)" />
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="field1" value="1" onclick="getscores1(this)" />
        <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="article">
        <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="field2" value="0" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="field2" value="1" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
        <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>     
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Is your drivers license suspended?</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="field3" value="0" onclick="getscores3(this)"/>
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="field3" value="1" onclick="getscores3(this)"/>
        <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="submitbutton" class="article">
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="answer(this)" onclick="location.href ='testSite.html';"/>
    </fieldset>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is what I have on the testSite.html which the submit button goes to

this is answer

This is the JavaScript page

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "testSite.html";
};

function getscores1(score1) {
    answer(score1.value);
}

function getscores2(score2) {
    answer(score2.value);
}

function getscores3(score3) {
    answer(score3.value);
}

function answer(score1, score2, score3) {
    if (score1 == 0 || score2 == 0 || score3 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "false";
    } else{
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "pass";
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Let me know if anything is confusing or anything and I'll fix it.

Comment: So basically you are loading a new page when you click on the submit button (with `location.href = "testSite.html";`) completely destroying the local scope and the state of the form inputs. Just stay on the same page ;-)

Comment: @Arsylum I need it to go to a new page because in the final draft will either go to another page with more questions or go to a page explaining why they didn't pass.

Comment: when the page is reloaded all previous scope is destroyed as @Arsylum described, you will always get the same value over and over again regardless - If going to next page is necessary then You can use `Session` to tempory store the choice and reload it when page is loaded and again Update the session when the SUBMIT button is cliked

Comment: @christiemattern (are you still looking for a sloultion, since this has been idle for some time now?) You can always have more questions, or explanations popping up on the same page with javascript. If you want to have multiple pages php might be a better choice for processing the form. If it has to be javascript on multiple pages save your state with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) before setting a new `location.href`

Answer (score -1):

My best guess looking at this is, if it's calculating wrong, it's probably because you're passing the submit input into your answer function so it will set score1 to that element, then score2 and score3 are undefined so they wouldn't equal 0 either.

Answer (score -1):

Save this as a file: my_html.html and run in the browser. Read the comments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <span>Total Score: </span> <span id="totalScore"></span>
  <form id="myForm">
    <fieldset class="article">
      <h3><legend>Eligibility Test</legend></h3>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="article">
      <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend> <input type="radio" name="field1" value="0" onclick="getscores1(this)"> <label>Yes</label> <input type="radio" name="field1" value="1" onclick="getscores1(this)"> <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="article">
      <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend> <input type="radio" name="field2" value="0" onclick="getscores2(this)"> <label>Yes</label> <input type="radio" name="field2" value="1" onclick="getscores2(this)"> <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Is your drivers license suspended?</legend> 
      <input type="radio" name="field3" value="0" onclick="getscores3(this)"> <label>Yes</label> 
      <input type="radio" name="field3" value="1" onclick="getscores3(this)"> <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="submitbutton" class="article">
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"> <!-- Don't do this: onclick="location.href ='testSite.html';" --> 
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

  <script>
    var s1, s2, s3;
    [s1, s2, s3] = [0, 0, 0];

    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
        //location.href = "testSite.html"; //JavaScript context is on the client side for the current page only. When you reload the page, it gets recreated, all variables are re-initialized.
        answer(s1, s2, s3);
    };

    function getscores1(score1) {
        s1 = score1.value;
    }

    function getscores2(score2) {
        s2 = score2.value;
    }

    function getscores3(score3) {
        s3 = score3.value;
    }

    function answer(score1, score2, score3) {
        if (score1 == 0 || score2 == 0 || score3 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "false";
        } else{
            document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "pass";
        }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

- ashishjainblogger@gmail.com